# places api key invalid

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have followed various questions and solutions as regards the `PLACES_API_KEY_INVALID` error. I have set up the credentials correctly and I am using the right API key in my **manifest.xml** but I still get the invalid API key error. I have searched and searched but no solution. I am trying to see if I can use the google play services version 11.2 which as stated on the documentation provides a new way of implementation, but its not downloading.
my current google play places version is 9.2. Here is the screenshot of my Google console screen:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming issue.

Comment: shouldnt it be a programming issue, or what issue should it be